# Keeps saying uint16 is not declared

Tags: c++, c

Ok I know this has got to be a simple question but for the life of me I can't figure out why I keep getting this message  I am using eclipse V3.8 on ubuntu linux V13.04

Compile says "unit16 has not been declared

```
#ifndef ENIGMA_2C_H_
#define ENIGMA_2C_H_

class Enigma2C {

public:
    static bool checkOptionKey(uint16 option, char *key);
    static bool encrypt (char *inString, char *outString);
    static bool decrypt (char *inString, char *outString);
};

#endif
```

Comment: `uint16` isn't a standard type.

Comment: Most probably this is a typedef or a define and you're missing the definition because you did not include the header.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that `uint16` has not been declared?

Answer (score 13):

Use `uint16_t` in `cstdint`, which is introduced in C++11. Or define your own type.

For C, it's in `stdint.h`, which is introduced in C99.

Comment: So you want to say, that in C++ I can be sure that `uint16_t` exists just if compiler supports C++11 in header `cstdint`, but for C, I can be sure it exists if compiler supports C99 in `stdint.h` ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `inttypes.h` anf the type is `uint16_t`. ie

```
#ifndef ENIGMA_2C_H_
#define ENIGMA_2C_H_

#include <inttypes.h>

class Enigma2C {

public:
    static bool checkOptionKey(uint16_t option, char *key);
    static bool encrypt (char *inString, char *outString);
    static bool decrypt (char *inString, char *outString);
};

#endif
```